# Extract MIN and MAX values related to datetime values on Postgres with a condition postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query a table that has a collection of values  recorded over time. I would like to produce a result set that grabs the first date and the last date where the value>170 consecutively.

I think I need to use the MIN and MAX functions and some subqueries to achieve this, but I'm just not getting the results I need.

Is there an effective way to achieve the results below on PostgreSQL?

Here's a sample of my data set :

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-07 15:30:30 | 169.6 |
| 2022-02-07 15:30:55 | 171 |
| 2022-02-07 15:31:10 | 170.9 |
| 2022-02-07 15:31:50 | 171.1 |
| 2022-02-07 15:32:00 | 172 |
| 2022-02-07 15:32:45 | 168 |
| 2022-02-07 15:33:20 | 168.7 |
| 2022-02-07 15:34:10 | 173.7 |
| 2022-02-07 15:34:55 | 171.5 |
| 2022-02-07 15:35:20 | 171.7 |
| 2022-02-07 15:36:05 | 163.5 |

the expected result:

| Date_start | Date_end | Value_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-07 15:30:55 | 2022-02-07 15:32:00 | 172 |
| 2022-02-07 15:34:10 | 2022-02-07 15:35:20 | 173.7 |

Comment: "consecutively" implies there's some kind of ordering. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have edited my question, you can see a sample of my dataset and the result I'm looking for.

Comment: You will have to use a window function - either LEAD or LAG, it does not matter too much. Your sliding window should be only 2 rows tall. You will check whether the value in the current row is >170 and whether the value in the next/previous row is >170. Since these are 2 boolean variables - you will have 4 combinations (00, 01, 10 and 11). 00 and 11 are not interesting. 01 will mark the MIN value (coming from the next row) and 10 will mark the MAX value (coming from the previous row). You can emit NULL for the 00 and 11 combinations.

Comment: You need to add a ROW_NUMBER() windowing function over the date, then filter out the values that are >170 then the result would like a gap and island when you will find non continuous rownum...

Comment: As I'm not familiar with these functions, can you write the code for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can use the traditional solution: using `LAG()` or `LEAD()`.

For example:

```
select min(date), max(date), max(value)
from (
  select *, sum(i) over(order by date) as g
  from (
    select *,
      case when (lag(value) over(order by date) > 170) <> (value > 170)
           then 1 else 0
      end as i
    from mytable
  ) x
) y
group by g
having max(value) > 170
order by g
```

Result:

```
 min                  max                  max   
 -------------------- -------------------- ----- 
 2022-02-07 15:30:55  2022-02-07 15:32:00  172.0 
 2022-02-07 15:34:10  2022-02-07 15:35:20  173.7
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7e200b1e31e80acf681fb6154ec4c535).